# Нужны ли кавычки в следующем предложении?

Tags: кавычки, названия

*К поколению "Y" обычно относят тех, кто появился на свет в 1984–1996 гг.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Кавычки не требуются:** название состоит из одной заглавной буквы, к тому же латинской. Можно сослаться на [ответ Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9&start=0) (Вопрос № 281354):

> Правила как такового нет: правила русского правописания не регламентируют написание названий, оформленных латиницей. Рекомендуя не заключать в кавычки подобные названия, мы руководствуемся здравым смыслом: написание латиницей в русском тексте само по себе является выделительным, зачем нужно дополнительное выделение кавычками?

[**Поколение Y**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_Y) (Википедия):

> **Миллениалы**, или **Поколение Y** (поколение «игрек»; другие названия: **поколение Миллениума** (millennials, **поколение «некст», «сетевое» поколение, миллениты, эхо-бумеры**) — поколение людей, родившихся примерно с 1981 по 1996 год...

[**Чем отличаются поколения Y и Z...**](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/ru-ru/consumer-insights/consumer-trends/z-y/)

> Поколение Y — люди, рожденные после 1981 года. Совершеннолетие они встретили уже в новом тысячелетии, поэтому часто их называют миллениалами. <...>
>
> Представителей поколения Z от миллениалов отделяет то, что они «родились со смартфоном в руках».

Еще **примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:**

*Если предыдущее поколение, которое называют Х, существовало в рамках «черное или белое», то нынешнее поколение Y ― вне рамок, то есть и черное, и белое заходят одинаково и без рефлексии.* [Ксения Гощицкая. Знакомьтесь, Лена Шейдлина... (2017.09.04)]

*Понятно, что часть присущих поколению Y свойств демонстрировали, будучи молодыми, и их старшие товарищи.* [Анастасия Матвеева. Амбициозные и бессмысленные // «Эксперт», 2014]